# Cannot retrieve FilterActivity object via SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am trying to retrieve **FilterActivity** object using SOAP API.

I tried with the following RetrieveRequest:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:Username xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">****</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">****</wsse:Password>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
  <RetrieveRequest>
    <ObjectType>FilterActivity</ObjectType>
    <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
    <Properties>FilterActivityID</Properties>
    <Properties>FilterDefinitionID</Properties>
    <Properties>DestinationObjectID</Properties>
    <Properties>DestinationTypeID</Properties>
    <Properties>SourceObjectID</Properties>
    <Properties>SourceTypeID</Properties>
    <Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
      <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
      <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
      <Value>EmailActivityFilter</Value>
    </Filter>
  </RetrieveRequest>
</RetrieveRequestMsg>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I got the response saying **Error: No view defined for the object type: FilterActivity**

After having looked at the [FilterActivity documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/filteractivity.htm) for available methods associated with this object and also at the [Retrieve method documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieve.htm), i found that it does not have a *Retrieve* method. So does this mean it is not a retrievable object?

I also went through the REST API documentation but did not find anything on filter activities.

After considering the above findings, how can i get the details of a FilterActivity object?

Any help/suggestions would be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A FilterActivity cannot be retrieved in a RetrieveRequest - only a Filter Definition can be retrieved through the SOAP API.

If you look at the [Documentation for a FilterActivity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/filteractivity.htm) you will see that it only supports the following API Request Types:

- Create
- Update
- Delete
- Perform

Therefore it cannot be retrieved at all and looks to be something that is retrieved exclusively in the Marketing Cloud UI